# HTML anchor too pull all Sticky Posts?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Is there a way to format an  tag to send a query, pull all Sticky Posts, and loop through them?

Since 'sticky' is not a category, I cant format the link in the normal :

http://mysite.com/category/cars

I'm thinking is probably going to have to be some kind of url query string sent in as GET.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor is not being sent to the serverside.
why not to make it http://mysite.com/sticky?

Comment: Resolved this by creating a page in WP; in that template I added the above query post filtering. The anchor was linked to that page. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve all sticky posts in WP you can try this code:

```
query_posts(array('post__in'=>get_option('sticky_posts')));
```

And then link to resulting page.